# Django Angularjs How to call Http request with specific Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, angularjs

i am very new in angularjs.I am trying to pull data in one of my django template using angularjs.This is the view by which i actually trying to pull data.

```
def download_history(request,download_id):
    from django.core import serializers
    download_history = DownloadHistory.objects.filter(user = request.user,pk=download_id)
    ctx_detail_history = serializers.serialize('json', download_history)

    return HttpResponse(ctx_detail_history)
```

this is the urls

```
url(r'^history_detail/(?P<download_id>\d+)/$',views.download_history,name = 'download_history'),
```

and this is my template where i am trying to pull data and trying to show in a jquery pop up modal.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title%}User Subscription {%endblock%}
{%block content%}

<div style="margin-top:100px;background-color:#85ADFF;" ng-app='history'>

    <table class="table table-striped" >
        {%for download_history_name in download_history%}
         <tr>

          <td><button type='button' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href={%url 'download_history' download_history_name.id %} >{{download_history_name.name}} and the id {{download_history_name.id}}</a></button></td>
         </tr>
        {%endfor%}
</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Objact Name</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped" ng-controller='HistoryCtrl'>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    {[{detail_history.fields.name}]}
                    {[{detail_history.fields.download_rate}]}
                    {[{detail_history.fields.photo.url}]}
                    {[{detail_history.fields.downloaded_time}]}
                    {[{detail_history.fields.DuePayment}]}
                </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




</div>  

{%block extrajs%}
<script>

var app = angular.module('history',[]);
app.config(function($httpProvider){
   $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
   $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';

});

app.config(function($interpolateProvider){
   $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
   $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');

});

app.controller('HistoryCtrl',['$scope','$http' , function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/history/history_detail/(? P<download_id>\d+)/').success(function(data){
          //$scope.doToggle=false;
          $scope.detail_history=data;
        }).error(function(data,status){
              $scope.data = data || 'Request Fails';
              $scope.status = status;
              console.log(data)
            });

  }]);
</script>


{%endblock%}

{%endblock%}
```

now the problem is ,though i am trying to pull data with a specific **id**,but its not working,, in fact if i inspect the page ,it shows the return URL something that

```
   http://localhost:8000/history/history_detail/(?Pd+)/
```

now whats the problem,definitely i make a mistake here,but i am very new in angularjs and can not figure it out.Is it possible to solve the problem using ng-click function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a cursory examination of your JavaScript it appears that you're trying to make a GET request to a URL including a regular expression. This makes sense for your Django configuration because you're telling the application to expect a number in the url that you assign to a variable named download_id. It appears you have copied this URL directly into your JavaScript where in fact you should be providing a specific download id in your GET request (e.g. '/history/history_detail/12345/').

Comment: The id will retrieve from the anchor tag .. after an event

Comment: @Tanweer except it won't, because you haven't written any code to do that.